# xmlHttpRequest.send(Params) not working in tomcat 7

Tags: javascript

I am trying to send some parameters through xmlHttpRequest.send(params) written in a JS file to my servlet where I try to get the parameters by req.getParameter("some_Parameter"); it returns null on the servlet. though if i send the parameters by appending them in url it works fine. but when the url will be large it will break the code. so please someone help me out.

Thanks in advance.

```
function doHttpPost(theFormName, completeActivity) 
{ 
    var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP"); 
    var xmlMessage = buildPOST(theFormName, completeActivity); 
    var responseTxt; 
    try { 
        xmlhttp.Open(document.forms[theFormName].method, document.forms[theFormName].action+'?'+xmlMessage, false); 
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() { 
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) { 
                responseTxt = xmlhttp.responseText; 
            } 
        } 
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        enableDisableLinks(true);
        setPointer();  
        xmlhttp.Send(); 
        if(xmlhttp.Status != 200) { 
            alert("Post to server failed"); 
        } 
    } catch (e) { 
        responseTxt = "Exception while posting form data: Error No: " + e.number + ", Message: " + e.description; 
    } 

    resetPointer();  
    enableDisableLinks(false);
    var expectedTxt = "Form Data had been successfully posted to the database." 
    if(responseTxt.toString() == expectedTxt.toString()) { 
        // MNP: New requirement from Jeanne, should not refresh CM page, commenting it off for now
        //if(completeActivity) {
        //  if (typeof (ViewCaseDetailBtn) != 'undefined') {
        //      ViewCaseDetailBtn.click();
        //  }
        //}
        return true; 
    } else {
        alert (responseTxt); 
    }
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: Instead of appending `xmlMessage` to the end of the URL, you need to pass it to the `xmlhttp.Send();`, like `xmlhttp.Send(xmlMessage);`

Comment: that is what I have tried exactly and not working. the code above i had posted was one that is working fine. when i try to pass it to xmlhttp.send(xmlMessage); it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

**BUGS**

```
//IE only - shooting yourself in the
// Not all IE versions use ActiveX!
var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");    foot. 

//JavaScript case sensitive, open !== Open
xmlhttp.Open(document.fo...

//JavaScript case sensitive, send !== Send
xmlhttp.Send();

//JavaScript case sensitive, status !== Status
xmlhttp.Status
```

AND if you are using synchronous, it does not call the onreadystatechange.

If you are using POST, the value needs to be in `send("valuestosendup")` not on the querystring.

This code shows why you should really use a framework to make Ajax calls and to not roll your own.

Comment: What's weird is that they say it "works", it just won't send the values unless they append them to the URL. So I'm wondering why these syntax errors aren't happening

Comment: What old IE browser are you using? The issue is, if you are posting, you need to do it is send(), no where do you show that in your code.

Comment: This isn't my question. I was pointing out that it was weird that the OP says it still works, even with the syntax errors like `.Send` and `.Status`

Comment: @Ian, lol, I did not even bother looking at the name. I thought it was weird the OP said it worked.